# PYTHON: need more than 0 values to unpack (compare 2 files)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to compare file1 column 0 with file2 column 0  and if they match, I want to output the rest of the information for matching rows from both files.

file1.txt:

```
 sb1,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,3.100000,8.400000
 sb2,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,6.100000,11.400001
 sb3,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,4.700000,10.000000
 sb4,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,40.100002,45.400002
 sb5,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,12.299999,17.600000
```

file2.txt:

```
 sb, VIRTUAL_IO.22_f.2,177.899994,180.500000
 sb1,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f.2,185.800003,188.300003
 sb4,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f.2,190.500000,193.000000
 sb5,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f.2,190.699997,193.200012
 sb8,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f.2,182.000000,184.599991
 sb9,VIRTUAL_IO.22_r.2,243.800003,246.300003
 sb2,VIRTUAL_IO.22_r.2,207.200012,209.800003
 sb7,VIRTUAL_IO.22_r.2,247.600006,250.099991
 sb8,VIRTUAL_IO.22_r.2,208.699997,211.199997
```

expected output:

```
 sb1,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,3.100000,8.400000,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f.2,185.800003,188.300003
 sb2,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,6.100000,11.400001,VIRTUAL_IO.22_r.2,207.200012,209.800003
 sb4,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,40.100002,45.400002,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f.2,190.500000,193.000000
 sb5,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f,12.299999,17.600000,VIRTUAL_IO.22_f.2,190.699997,193.200012
```

code:

```
 f1 = file("file1.txt")
 f2 = file("file2.txt")


 d = {}
 while True:
   line = f1.readline()
   if not line:
      break
   c0,c1,c2,c3 = line.split()
   d[c0] = (c0,c1,c2,c3)
 while True:
   line = f2.readline()
   if not line:
      break
 c0,c1,c2,c3 = line.split()
 if (c0) in d:
    vals = d[c0]
    print c0,vals[1],vals[2],vals[3],c1,c2,c3
```

the issue of current code is i have this error:

```
      c0,c1,c2,c3 = line.split()
      ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Use `split(',')` instead of `split()`.

Comment: did not work, i got another error
    **c0,c1,c2,c3 = line.split(',')**
**ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**

Comment: The second `line.split()` (and the `if` under it) should be indented.

Comment: actually, i already put (',') for both line.split. still not working. may i know what meant "should be indented"?

Comment: Have you tried indenting the second `split()` and the `if` below it? Shouldn't these lines be in the body of the second `while` loop?

Comment: sorry i cannot get what you meant? can you point me which part i need to change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221690/discussion-between-siti-nadhirah-zainurin-and-kol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are three problems:

- If you call `split` without specifying a separator, it will separate at whitespaces. You need to split lines at commas.
- The second `split` call and the `if` below it are not indented. Indentation is needed to move them into the body of the second `while` loop.
- In the `if` you shouldn't use parentheses around `c0`.

You should also `strip` the EOL characters from the lines read from the files, and use `join` to create the desired comma-separated output.

```
f1 = file("file1.txt")
f2 = file("file2.txt")

d = {}

while True:
  line = f1.readline().strip()
  if not line:
    break
  c0,c1,c2,c3 = line.split(",")
  d[c0] = (c0,c1,c2,c3)

while True:
  line = f2.readline().strip()
  if not line:
    break
  c0,c1,c2,c3 = line.split(",")
  if c0 in d:
    vals = d[c0]
    print ",".join([c0,vals[1],vals[2],vals[3],c1,c2,c3])
```